# Google Sheets Formula in every new row

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I want to be able to copy over the formula once a new row gets created at the end. I have an automated process to create a row at the end of a google sheet but this does not carry over formulas that are places in the sheet or in a column

I have not been able to find a solution

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't provided more context we're not able to give you a more specific answer; but look into ArrayFormulas. They're meant to cover a whole range. For example, in C2 you could put this formula and it will automatically cover all C column:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A+B2:B)
```

It's not always this direct and easy, but research on this and let us know if you need more help!